# If there's a small probability particles may teleport anywhere in an infinite Universe, shouldn't stars pop up in existence close to us ever so often?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, cosmology, quantum-teleportation

I've been having a question on the top of my mind for a while, and didn't really manage to get it solved, so I'm asking it here:

Assuming that particles may "teleport" (or superposition, or even more technically - the wave function) anywhere in the universe, but with an unreasonably small probability and that the universe is infinite, souldn't stars pop up in existence close to us ever so often?

Let me be more detailed:
If the universe is infinite, there should be infinite many stars (most likely). And with infinite stars, there are also infinite atoms, that could superposition. And with infinite particles that superposition, there should also be infinite particles that superposition far away. And a few (tini tiny number compared to the rest of the universe, but still infinite, since the probability of this happening is not 0, and there are infinitely many particles) stars  should synchronize ever so often and superposition somewhere else. Having said this shouldn't stars just pop up into existence next to us ever so often?

It's a question that has been bugging me for a while and I'm really curious for an answer. I'm no expert - I'm an electronics engineer, but been reading about these facts, and they've been stuck in my head.

Really appreciate any kind of answer

Comment: Have you got a rough back of the envelope calculation of how often "every so often" should be?

Comment: Also....is there any particular reason you focused on stars popping into existence as opposed to, say, giraffes?

Comment: There are alot more stars than giraffes

Comment: I think the point of @WillO is that, according to your argument, there are an infinite number of stars because the universe is infinite, but by that logic there should also be an infinite number of giraffes. If there are both a (countably) infinite number of stars and giraffes, then it does not make sense to say that there are more stars than giraffes.

Answer (score 4):

No, an infinite universe does not make this likely.

As the distance from earth increases (on cosmological scales) the number of atoms increases with the square of the distance. So, in order for the probability of tunneling to increase with increasing distance the probability density of each atom can decay no faster than $1/r^3$ which means that the wavefunction can decay no faster than $1/r^{3/2}$. But the wave function for tunneling decays exponentially, which is far faster.

So no single atom will tunnel out of the potential well of a star, let alone an entire star which would require all of those atoms to do so at the same time in the same direction. Even with an infinite universe.

Comment: link for tunneling http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/barr.html

Comment: +1 for a much more concise and quantified answer

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you are looking for is tunneling, which is very different from superposition. I will not go into detail about how these things work, as suitable problems to demonstrate these concepts are readily available online or in textbooks.

Instead let me say qualitatively that even for a small particle like an electron to tunnel through a potential barrier, the probability drops off rapidly with the size of the barrier ("height" in the sense of strength of the potential and spacial width).

Now, let's say the probability of an electron from the next nearest star to tunnel to our solar system is one in one billion. Given the massive distances involved, this is already probably a VERY generous guess. For an entire atom, the probability is even less. Why? Because if the probability of each constituent particle tunneling that distance is at most 1 in 1,000,000,000, and there are n particles in the atom, the probability will be at most (1E-9)^n for the entire atom. Now consider how many atoms make up a star. I think you see where this is going.

While technically not forbidden by quantum mechanics, the probability of an entire star *coherently* tunneling from a far away solar system to our own is so mind numbingly small it may as well be zero. I would expect you would have better luck trying to tunnel into the next room by running head first into the wall, but please do not try that.

Comment: I agree. But give infinitely many stars, and infinitely many particles, shouldn't it happen literally all the time? Take in consideration that something very very very EXTREMELY small * infinite > 0.

Comment: In response to your point I would add that 1) the universe is not known to be infinite and in many modern cosmological theories it is assumed to be finite and 2) Even assuming it is infinite in spatial extent it does not necessarily follow that there is infinite stuff like atoms and stars. BUT even if there was and we assumed a roughly uniform distribution of said stuff, the number of places stuff could tunnel too should grow exactly in proportion to the amount of stuff and the probability would at best be unchanged. So I'm not sure what you mean by multiplying by infinity.

Comment: Even if it happens infinitely often, if the universe is infinitely large, the chances of it happening near you would still be zero.

Comment: We need to calculate the limit...